# forked process cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following command:

```
var fk = cp.fork('./client/processes/getClipboardImage.js',[],{cwd: __dirname + '/../../'});
```

Which then runs this:

```
"use strict";
const electron_1 = require('electron');
var base64Image = electron_1.clipboard.readImage().toDataURL();
process.emit('got-string', base64Image);
```

I am not sure why, but I get an error saying:

> Cannot find module 'electron'

The file that inits the fork does have access to electron, so why doesn't forked process?

[image]

The executing file is in `controllers` which runs a method in `utils/Workpace.js` and that method creates the fork.

**client/controllers/index.js**

```
import { Workspace } from '../../client/utils/Workspace';
import { globals } from '../../client/utils/global';

ipcRenderer.on('workspace.paste', e => {
    if (globals.activeWorkspace) {
        globals.activeWorkspace.pasteToLayer();
    }
});
```

**client/utils/Workspace.js**

```
import cp = require('child_process');

export class Workspace {
    public pasteToLayer(/*image: Electron.NativeImage*/): Promise<Layer> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            var fk = cp.fork('./client/processes/getClipboardImage.js',[],{cwd: __dirname + '/../../'});
            fk.on('got-string', (err, out) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                // do some final thigs
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**client/utils/global.js**

```
import { Workspace } from '../../client/utils/Workspace';

export class globals {

    public static activeWorkspaceId: string;
    public static activeWorkspace: Workspace;

}
```

Comment: Where is the file that calls `cp.fork`? It looks like `__dirname + '/../../'` might go up 1 too many levels?

Comment: The file that actually calls it is `Workspace.js`

Comment: Huh? Isn't the path from `Workspace.js` to there `../processes/getClipboardImage.js`?

Comment: `client/controllers/index.js -> client/utils/Workspace.js -> client/processes/getClipboardImage.js`

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this `cwd: __dirname + '/../../'` is bringing you above
the level containing node_modules .

Its is hard to be sure with out more information as to the directory structure .

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot and a description

Comment: ok it looks like for sure that the cd you are doing is a higher level then the node_modules folder . So when it recurses up you folder structure its going past node_modules and node_modules is no longer available .

Comment: Cwd is in the root of the build folder. The build folder is a sibling of the node_modules folder.